# echo внутри echo

Tags: php, html

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как внутрь `echo` поместить ещё один `echo`?
Имеется такой кусок кода:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select, MYSQLI_BOTH)){
    echo "<div class=\"jumbotron\"></div>";
}
```

Внутри `div` должен находится `$row["id"]`, но как-то вообще не получается это реализовать.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кроме упомянутых **@cheops** методов можно вспомнить еще и функцию [`printf`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.printf.php):

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    printf('<div class="jumbotron">%s</div>', $row['id']);
}
```

**Замечание:**

По-хорошему, вам следует отделять представление от логики приложения. В качестве шаблонизатора на первых порах можно использовать сам PHP:

**index.php**

```
<?php

// ... Получаем некие данные из бд и помещаем результат в переменную $data
$data = mysqli_fetch_all($select, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

include "index.tpl.php"

mysqli_free_result($select);
mysqli_close($connection);
```

**index.tpl.php**

```
<?php foreach($data as $row): ?>
    <div class="jumbotron"><?= $row['id']; ?></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

В этом случае обычно прибегают к интерполяции элемента массива

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select, MYSQLI_BOTH)){
   echo "<div class=\"jumbotron\">{$row['id']}</div>";
}
```

Возможно также объединение строк при помощи оператора .

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select, MYSQLI_BOTH)){
   echo "<div class=\"jumbotron\">" . $row['id'] . "</div>";
}
```

Или перечисление выводимых элементов через запятую

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select, MYSQLI_BOTH)){
   echo "<div class=\"jumbotron\">" , $row['id'] , "</div>";
}
```